# how to simulate error handling for cd in c

Tags: c, bash

I'm working on a C project, the goal of it is to create a simulate of bash using C.

now I'm trying to simulate errors for cd and I faced this error.

NOTE: I'm not allowed to use exec functions.

**Why I asked this Question:**

there's a problem I faced when i was handling problems this is the problem:
when I create a directory and cd to this directory and delete it while I'm in it I get this error message in bash:

`cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory`

this is screenshot of the hole script **FROM BASH**:
[image]

is there's a way I can handle this error with?

the code of cd:

```
int ft_cd(t_args *args, t_env **head)
{
    char *buff;
    char *dir;
    t_env *temp;
    
    buff = NULL;
    if (args == NULL)
    {
        temp = ft_search_in_list(head, "HOME");
        if (temp == NULL)
            return (ft_put_err("cd:", " HOME not set", 1));
        dir = temp->value;
    }
    else if (args->next != NULL)
        return (ft_put_err("cd:", " too many arguments", 1));
    else if (!(ft_strcmp(args->value, "-")))
    {
        temp = ft_search_in_list(head, "OLDPWD");
        if (temp == NULL)
            return (ft_put_err("cd:", " OLDPWD not set", 1));
        dir = temp->value;
    }
    else
        dir = args->value;
    if (!getcwd(buff, 100))
        ft_put_err("getcwd: ", strerror(errno), 1);
    temp = ft_search_in_list(head, "PWD");
        if (temp == NULL)
            ft_add_to_list(head, ft_create_node("PWD", ""));
    temp = ft_search_in_list(head, "OLDPWD");
        if (temp == NULL)
            ft_add_to_list(head, ft_create_node("OLDPWD", ""));
    if (chdir(dir) == -1)
        return (ft_put_err("cd: ", ft_strjoin(dir, ft_strjoin(": ", strerror(errno))), 1));
    // ft_strjoin(dir, ": No such file or directory")
    temp = ft_search_in_list(head, "PWD");
    ft_replaceit(head, "OLDPWD", temp->value);
    ft_replaceit(head, "PWD", getcwd(buff, 100));
    return (0);
}
```

explain the code:
`t_env **head`: this is a linked list contain the environment.
`t_args *arg`: this is a linked list contain all the args of command.

Comment: Where does the message `error retrieving current directory:` come from? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: the message not from my code this message from bash (the screenshot not form my code it's from bash)

Comment: `getcwd()` can't work if the current directory has been deleted. It works by following the parent directory links in each directory, but deleting a directory removes it from its parent.

Comment: @Barmar so how can I handle this error?

Comment: Change `ft_put_err("getcwd: ", strerror(errno), 1);` to `ft_put_err("getcwd: error retrieving current directory: something seomthing", strerror(errno), 1);`? Please do not post pictures of code. Bash is open source, [here is the source](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/builtins/common.c#L635).

Comment: @DarkSide77 It looks like you're already handling it with `if (!getcwd(buff, 100))`